# SSRS - Data Driven Subscription, avoid using special character in filename. There are no special characters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, data-driven

I'm using SSRS Data Driven subscriptions to produce 300,000+ word documents (.docx).

The majority are being produced fine however, some are reporting an error of

> The filename is invalid. Avoid using special characters such as /\?*<>:|+,[]"&

All the filename are consecutive numbers starting from 10000000. One of them failing, for example, is 10898392, so no special characters and no trailing spaces etc.

I cannot work out why this is happening - any thoughts on this appreciated.

Comment: are you sure there are no hidden characters?

Comment: Hi Harry,  thanks, how do I reveal hidden characters?

Comment: Hi Nick, How do you generate your file names?

Comment: Using IDENTITY(10000000,1) on the table, Link Id's are inserted into the table so the ID's are created during the insert

Comment: Are you able to explicitly convert the generated file name into bigint for a test and see if it fails or runs ok?

Comment: The process is currently running as part of a dry run migration, I need to wait till it's finished to run a test of it.  I'll set the column type to bigint and repopulate it and try it again.  Do you know why having it as bigint may solve the problem?  Or is it just a hunch (I can work with hunches :))

Comment: I've had to deal with such stuff before and I work via process of elimination.. just a hunch to be honest..

Comment: Ok, cool.  I'll give that a go once it's finished.  Thanks.